# ASP.NET MVC- Selenium Webdriver timing out on Appharbor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download a web page using Selenium WebDriver (Firefox driver). Since the page is loaded dynamically with javascript, my code executes some javascript after initial page load to load the content. Trouble is that the WebDriver is timing out after a few minutes and I need at least 10 minutes to load all the content. Is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```
string firefoxBinaryPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/lib/mozilla firefox/firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxBinaryPath);
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        List<IWebElement> listOfDomElements = new List<IWebElement>();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        do
        {
            for (int second = 0; ; second++)
            {
                if (second >= 12)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,750)", "");//this is where it's timing out (line 103)
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        ...additional lines
        ...additional lines
```

This is the stacktrace and error i'm getting:

Source: WebDriver;
Message: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7058/hub/session/7c64141c-1792-4175-a5f6-5304d911b4da/execute timed out after 180 seconds.;
Stacktrace:    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at Amazon_Top_Products_Comparer.ParseMainStaplesDeals.ParseDom(String url) in d:\temp\npe0b3yh.ixi\input\Amazon Top Products Comparer\ParseMainStaplesDeals.cs:line 103
   at Amazon_Top_Products_Comparer.Controllers.HomeController.List(String category) in d:\temp\npe0b3yh.ixi\input\Amazon Top Products Comparer\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 84

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use sleep.

Try using

```
 this.Find.Element(By.XPath("Xpath to any element that loads at the end"));
```

or

```
 this.WaitUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("Id of element that loads at the end")));
```

I use the above codes in my page object. These lines are enough to produce required wait for certain element to be available. Am not sure if it waits for 10 mins. Give a try

Comment: Problem is that i'm loading a page that I have no way of knowing how many elements there are. I have to keep clicking "Load more Items" until the button is disabled.

Comment: Is it same button to be clicked always? something like infinite scroll??